# Xamarin - Swipeable cardview in recyclerview?

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin

I am going through the **fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView**. The sample app is running fine.

Here you would find a code and sample of this library 
https://github.com/chrisriesgo/android-swipelistview-sharp

Here's an xml file:

```
<com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/example_lv_list"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
        swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
        swipe:swipeDrawableChecked="@drawable/choice_selected"
        swipe:swipeDrawableUnchecked="@drawable/choice_unselected"
        swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"
        swipe:swipeMode="both"
        swipe:swipeActionRight="reveal"
        swipe:swipeActionLeft="dismiss"
        swipe:swipeOpenOnLongPress="false" />
```

Here's my code

```
[Activity(Label = "Swipe ListView", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : FragmentActivity
    {
        SwipeListView _swipeListView;
        DogsAdapter _adapter;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            ActionBar.SetIcon(new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent));

            _swipeListView = FindViewById<SwipeListView>(Resource.Id.example_lv_list);

            _adapter = new DogsAdapter(this, Dogs.GetDogData());

            _swipeListView.FrontViewClicked += HandleFrontViewClicked;
            _swipeListView.BackViewClicked += HandleBackViewClicked;
            _swipeListView.Dismissed += HandleDismissed;

            _swipeListView.Adapter = _adapter;
        }

        void HandleFrontViewClicked (object sender, SwipeListViewClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this,"click",ToastLength.Short);
            RunOnUiThread(() => _swipeListView.OpenAnimate(e.Position));
            //my Stuff to do currently a toast
RunOnUiThread(()=>Toast.MakeText(Application.Context,"click",ToastLength.Short));
        }

        void HandleBackViewClicked (object sender, SwipeListViewClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() => _swipeListView.CloseAnimate(e.Position));
        }

        void HandleDismissed (object sender, SwipeListViewDismissedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var i in e.ReverseSortedPositions)
            {
                _adapter.RemoveView(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I am adding extra stuffs to the code that are not executed.

Currently I've added a toast in  **HandleFrontViewClicked** in two possible ways but none of them fires.

**I want to ask two questions:**

1. How can I do my required things lets say display a toast
2. How to detect left of rightswipe in the code

Thanks for your help

Comment: did you find the problem?